# Javascript Shell Sort implementation is quicker then Merge Sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I got two implementation of the algorithms: one is shell sort, the other is merge sort. 
Shell sort complexity is something near n^1.5 and merge sort is n * logn, so basically merge sort should be quicker. However, on my test I see different results: shell sort much quicker then merge sort. I believe I am doing something wrong, however not seeing this.

Shell Sort implementaion:

```
var shell_sort = function(array){
    var length = array.length;
    var h = 1;
    while( h < length / 3){
        h = 3 * h + 1;
    }

    while( h > 0 ){
        for ( var i = h; i < length; i++){

            for ( var j = i; j > 0 && array[j] < array[j-h]; j-=h){
                array.swap(j, j-h);
            }
        }
        //decreasing h
        h = --h / 3

    }
    return array;
};
```

And Merge Sort:

```
var merge_sort = function(array){      
    function merge(left, right){
        var result = [];
        var il = 0;
        var ir = 0;

        while (il < left.length && ir < right.length){
          if (left[il] < right[ir]){
            result.push(left[il++]);
          } else {
            result.push(right[ir++]);
          }
        }

        if ( il < left.length){
            result.push.apply(result,left.slice(il));
        } 

        if (ir < right.length){
            result.push.apply(result,right.slice(ir));
        }

        return result;
    }

    function merge_sort(items){
        //well it is only 1 element
        if (items.length < 2){
            return items;
        }

        var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2);

        //create two arrays
        var left = items.slice(0, middle);
        var right = items.slice(middle);

        return merge(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right));
    }

    return merge_sort(array);

};
```

Basically results on arrays of 10 million elements is next:

Shell sort : 12725ms

Merge Sort: 34338ms

Test is very simple:

```
//sorting 100000 elements
array.generate_numbers(10000000);
console.time('10000000elements');
sort_algs(array);
console.timeEnd('10000000elements');
```

Where generate_numbers is simple helper function which generates array of numbers with configured size, as well as swap is a function which changes element positions.

Comment: you simply cannot count on CS101 performance estimations made for compiled code to hold up when run on modern cores like V8 with it's own set of optimizations and bottlenecks. in short, it could be object access or the performance of [].slice() vs [].push() that's being timed more than the actual algo; who knows... at any rate, you should use the built-in [].sort() for the best performance.

Comment: i though that:) but really interested what makes this work soooo slow:)

Comment: you can insert timers into the code itself to trace perf, though you'll want to step-through much smaller arrays doing that... looking at the code, it seems your merge sorts needs a bunch of new arrays, each in their own scope whereas the first one keeps it all in one scope, which saves a lot of tear-down and provides more optimization opportunities.

Comment: "so basically merge sort should be quicker" only if you chose *n* large enough, which evidently you didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone interested, find sources of algo with out so many arrays:

```
var merge_sort = function(array){      
    function merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi ){

        for (var k = lo; k <= hi; k++){
            aux[k] = a[k];
        }
        debugger;
        var i = lo;
        var j = mid + 1;
        for (var k = lo; k <= hi; k++){
            if ( i > mid) a[k] = aux[j++];
            else if ( j > hi ) a[k] = aux[i++];
            else if ( aux[j] < aux[i]) a[k] = aux[j++];
            else a[k] = aux[i++];
        }
    }

    function sort(array, aux, lo, hi){
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        var mid = Math.floor(lo + (hi - lo) / 2);

        sort(array, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(array, aux, mid + 1, hi);

        merge(array, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    function merge_sort(array){
        var aux = array.slice(0);
        sort(array, aux, 0, array.length - 1);
        return array;
    }

    return merge_sort(array);

};
```

Comment: Nice example, but I believe you've forgot to delete rows 3->5.
By the way, I've compared Merge Sort with Shell Sort and with the native Array.prototype.sort() using an array with a length of 10 millions. Shell Sort took something like 1.5 * Merge Sort Time, a bit slower, and the native Array.prototype.sort() took something like 2.5 * Merge Sort Time. But in Big O notation constants like these are not important.

Answer (score 3):

At a high level, your shell sort implementation relies primarily on the call to swap(), while the merge sort involves a number of array accesses and manipulations.  Quite simply, the ratio of logic handled by built in functions vs. your script is much higher in the shell sort, and in interpreted languages, that will generally result in faster execution.

In your particular case, the merge sort will be creating a new array on every call to merge(), calling .push() on that array a number of times, and eventually discarding the array when it is merged.  The shell sort does every thing in place, and never needs to create or destroy arrays.  Therefore, the performance of your merge sort relative to the shell sort is going to be heavily influenced by the characteristics of the garbage collection used by your browser.

If I remember correctly, a traditional analysis of merge sort assumes that creating, extending, and destroying arrays are are all roughly constant time operations.  This is probably not the case in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can see Sedgewick's merge sort implementation: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html
he use copy of input array to maintain small arrays inside merge_sort function, so he does not have any overhead with array creation and pushing elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does mergeSort need a bunch of new arrays, as @dandavis remarked, but they are also automatically growing – i.e. you define them as empty (`result = []`) and then repetitively `push` elements onto the end. This takes a lot of time as the runtime will have allocate and then re-allocate enough space for these arrays.

Since the length of the final array is known beforehand (you're just merging `left` and `right` whose lengths you both know), try allocating the result to its final size fro the get-go (i.e. `result = new Array(left.length + right.length)`) and write to it by index instead.